# How to see the list of files checked in to MKS after creating the devpath?

Tags: mks, mks-integrity

After creating the devpath in MKS, developers will check in the code to MKS. I want to find the list of files got checked in to the MKS after creation of devpath (from the beginning to the end).
 Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the command line interface "rlog" command to see all changes on a devpath.

The basic syntax would be something like: `si rlog --devpath=Version2`

You can also use the other parameters of the rlog command to limit the output to a date range or other criteria.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the GUI you can go to the "project history view", and mark two of the checkpoint bubbles (holding CTRL) and then select "view differences" from the context menu. In that view you can see all the files that were checked in between the selected checkpoints.